# Check writing software for Linux Mint 17

Tags: software-rec, printing

I'm trying to switch from Windows. I have check writing software (Avanquest Softcheck) for Windows; unfortunately they don't support Linux. Looked into gnucash and moneydance, but they only print preprinted checks. I need software that will print everything onto a completely blank check stock including micr numbers. Tried to use virtual software but I guess I'm not proficient enough to get them working. I don't want to go back to Windows (this the only issue that is keeping me from going 100% Linux). Please let me know if there is any other software or packages out there I could use or if someone can come with something.

Comment: TIL people still use checks

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it under wine, software from similar line of products have gold status of testing, this is old test results but it can be useful:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23096

Check information and tutorials about wine at wine wiki http://wiki.winehq.org/

Check [Kraft](http://volle-kraft-voraus.de/) also